# Retrieving String Data incorrectly SQL Lite - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am facing a problem when retrieving string types from my SQL Lite Db. When ever I store my Strings into the SQL Lite DB, the Strings store correctly, However when I try to retreive these Strings, it returns more than what I stored. If this is confusing here is my code `db.storeNames(EVENTNAMES);`
 (EVENTNAMES is a List)

```
    public void storeNames(List<String> names)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_LABEL, names.get(i)); // Info Name

        db.insert(TABLE_INFO, null, values);
        // Closing database connection
    }

    Log.i("DB MESSAGE ", names.size() + " NAMES STORED");

    db.close();
}
```

Then I retrieve

```
        eventName = db.getEventName();
```

And here is the corresponding DB code.

```
public List<String> getEventName() {
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_INFO;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(1);

            nameList.add(name);

        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
        Log.i("POSITION ", " NAMES "+ cursor.getPosition() + " RETRIEVED");

    }


    db.close();
    // return info list
    return nameList;
}`
```

Why is it retrieving more than it is supposed too. The Log message from the getNames() method prints out "NAMES (3x Number it should be) Retrieved.

```
**EDIT**

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    EVENTNAMES.add("EVENT 1");
    EVENTNAMES.add("EVENT 2");
    EVENTNAMES.add("EVENT 3");
    EVENTNAMES.add("EVENT 4");
    EVENTNAMES.add("EVENT 5");



    db.storeNames(EVENTNAMES);



}
```

Comment: So you called `storeNames` three times?

Comment: @CL. No but the program behaves like I did.

Comment: And only when I am retreiving. But from my log message it seems as if it stores correctly. @CL.

Comment: When exactly does your app call `storeNames`?

Comment: In the oncreate method. There is only one activity @CL.

Comment: Ok here Ive added @CL.

Comment: You have very questionable programming style mister .. what about naming conventions etc? Anyway, as was said before, if you open your activity multiple times and always insert new data in onCreate, its logical that that data will be there multiple times ..

Comment: Excuse me @Billda but my naming conventions are traditional lower camel case. And im sure my naming conventions have nothing to do with the problem. But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

When the activity is opened multiple times for the same database, new events are added to any existing events already stored in the database.
If you want to replace all events in the database, you must delete any old ones before storing the new ones.

Comment: hmm. So wait is onCreate called even when I make activity objects? Like say Activity a = new Activity();??